# Error while storing looped checkbox's value - Android

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have a program that will shows AlertDialog with some looped checkbox (checkboxes values come from database), then user will choose the checkbox, after that I want to store all the chosen checkbox to a variable, then store the value to database.

So the flow is :
Read value From Database -> Print all the value (loop) to Alert Dialog checkbox -> User check the checkbox then click OK -> the value of chosen checkbox will be stored and pass to DBHelper

I Have tried to code it, it runs good till when I want to store the value of the chosen checkbox, but I get error and the error is java.lang.NullPointerException..
Here I store the selected value to a string temp[i] (See the builder.setPositiveButton), then outside the loop, I pass the temp[i] to the groupToBePosted
This is my Code, wish you could help me to store the value and pass it to the database,,

Thank you..

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.bBrowseSelectGroup:
        myDb.open();
        final String[] groupName = myDb.fetchGroupName(username);
        myDb.close();
        final boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[groupName.length];
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                CreateAnnouncementActivity.this);

        builder.setTitle("Choose Your Group : ");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                myDb.open();
                final String[] groupId = myDb.fetchGroupId(username);
                myDb.close();
                String selectedGroup="Post To : ";
                String temp[] = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < groupName.length; i++) {
                if (itemsChecked[i]) {
                    temp[i]=groupId[i];
                    selectedGroup=selectedGroup+groupName[i]+", ";
                    itemsChecked[i]=false;
                }
            }

             PostTo.setText(selectedGroup); //Set the TextView Value

             for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
                 groupToBePosted[i]=temp[i];
             }

            }
        });
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(groupName, new boolean[] { false,
                false, false },
                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        itemsChecked[which] = isChecked;
                    }
                });
        builder.show();

        myDb.close();
        break;

    case R.id.bDoPostAnnouncement:


        //Get all the data stored and pass to the database
        for(int i=0; i<groupToBePosted.length;i++){
            myDb.open();
            myDb.insertNewAnnouncement(title, detail, time, groupToBePosted[i], username);
            myDb.close();
        }




        break;
    }
}
```

And here is the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a LinkedList:

```
LinkedList<String> temp =  new LinkedList<String>();
```

Then replace

```
temp[i]=groupId[i];
```

by

```
temp.add(groupId[i]);
```

Then later iterate over the list instead the temp array. Change:

```
for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
    groupToBePosted[i]=temp[i];
}
```

to

```
int i=0;
for(String t:temp){
    groupToBePosted[i]=t;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but It still get the error java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Ok, your code has several other assumptions that will fail if you use the array, so see my modification that uses a LinkedList.

Comment: Linkedlist is not same with array? Thank you for your help, I'm still trying with the code

Comment: See my latest changes. Btw: learning the Java API will help you and is recommended. Your question is quite trivial and might get a negative voting.

Comment: Thank you @brummfondel, yes I kinda new to java programming and OOP, but the code still doesnt work